# c#: Invalid Cast Exception

Tags: c#

can anyone help me out with this, i'm really struggling to work out how to correct this error:

```
public class ModDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModDataGridView dgv2 = new ModDataGridView();
        pnl.Controls.Add(dgv2); //pnl is a Panel type
        foreach (ModDataGridView item in pnl.Controls)
        {
            txt.AppendText(item.GetType().ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

An unhandled exception of type

> 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Test.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to type 'Test.ModDataGridView'.

Comment: what is the type of `pnl.Controls` ?

Comment: Is the error on foreach (ModDataGridView item in pnl.Controls)?

Comment: it's just a panel....will add to question!

Comment: @RudyTheHunter: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you only want to add the `ModDataGridView`?

You might make use of the `OfType<>()`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModDataGridView dgv2 = new ModDataGridView();
        pnl.Controls.Add(dgv2); //pnl is a Panel type
        foreach (ModDataGridView item in pnl.Controls.OfType<ModDataGridView>())
        {
            txt.AppendText(item.GetType().ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

---

If you want all controls, use a base class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModDataGridView dgv2 = new ModDataGridView();
        pnl.Controls.Add(dgv2); //pnl is a Panel type
        foreach (Control item in pnl.Controls)
        {
            txt.AppendText(item.GetType().ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymouse type `var`

```
foreach (var item in pnl.Controls)
   {
      if(item.GetType() == typeof(ModDataGridView))
       {
          txt.AppendText(item.GetType().ToString());
       }
   }
```

Comment: thanks, that works(in terms of not getting an error) but the problem i've posted above is a reduced problem from my original. i specifically want to get each object of type ModDataGridView and run some code on it, the above would just find objects of every type!

Comment: great happy coding :)

Comment: hey, i upvoted the answer(plus the other one) but since my posts are <15 it's not going to publicly display the upvote apparently....

Comment: ohh got it, no problem